# Multiple Results being uploaded to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

I've been struggling with trying to add the same variable into two of the tables I have on my database and so have decided to work around it and use two separate insert statements instead

```
if ($cuisinetype !='empty'){                                                                            
    $query="SELECT cuisine_type FROM `Nation` WHERE cuisine_type='$cuisine'";                                   
    $result=mysqli_query($db_server, $query) ;                                                                      

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $message = "Sorry we already have that one!";
    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO`Nation`(cuisine_type)VALUES('$cuisine')";                                     
        mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);                                                     
        mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) ;                                                                     
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO`recipename`(cuisine_type)VALUES('$cuisine')";                                                
        mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);                                                                 
        mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) ;                                                                     
    }
}
```

This is how my sql statement looks right now, but now it's putting two variables into my Nation table and still nothing into the `recipename` table

Still relatively new to all things PHP/MySQL and considering beforehand it was working am very confused.

Comment: You used `mysqli_real_escape_string` on `$cuisine`, didn't you?

Comment: Your second insert should be `mysqli_query($db_server, $query2) or ...`

Comment: @MarkBaker you are my hero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this under your second insert: 
`mysqli_query($db_server, $query2)` or  ... Replace the `$query` with `$query2`